# show axes on click - matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox, matlab-guide

I have a listbox button , lets say it contain 3 options : '1' '2' '3'.
I also have 5 axes.
When '2' is selected I plot something on this 5 axes.
What I wanted to know is how to make 5 more axes that will be shown only in case '3' is selected . 
I mean that the user wont be able to see axes 6~10 untill he will press on '3' and if he press '1' or '2' then again the user won't be able to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the axes that share the same properties (i.e. are visible or not at the same time) into 1 variable (eg. `TopAxes` and `BottomAxes`) and thus update their properties at the same time in the Listbox callback.

Here is an example with 6 axes, 3 at the top and 3 at the bottom. When the user selects "1" , all the axes are visible. When "2" is selected, only the top axes are and when "3" is selected only the bottom axes are visible. Here is the code with screenshots:

```
function ShowAxesGUI

clear
clc

hFig = figure('Position',[100 100 600 600]);

%// Create axes
handles.ax1 = axes('Position',[.1 .6 .2 .2]);
handles.ax2 = axes('Position',[.4 .6 .2 .2]);
handles.ax3 = axes('Position',[.7 .6 .2 .2]);

%// Group top axes together
handles.TopAxes= [handles.ax1;handles.ax2;handles.ax3];

handles.ax4 = axes('Position',[.1 .2 .2 .2]);
handles.ax5 = axes('Position',[.4 .2 .2 .2]);
handles.ax6 = axes('Position',[.7 .2 .2 .2]);

%// Group bottom axes together
handles.BottomAxes= [handles.ax4;handles.ax5;handles.ax6];

set(handles.BottomAxes,'Visible','off')

%//  Create listbox

handles.listbox1 = uicontrol('Style','list','Position',[50 520 60 60],'Value',1,'String',{'1';'2';'3'},'Callback',@(s,e) ListCallback);

guidata(hFig,handles)

    %// Listbox callback
    function ListCallback

        handles = guidata(hFig);

        %// Get the selected item in the listbox
        ListSelection = get(handles.listbox1,'Value');

        switch ListSelection

            case 1                
                set(handles.TopAxes,'Visible','on')
                set(handles.BottomAxes,'Visible','on')
            case 2
                set(handles.TopAxes,'Visible','on')
                set(handles.BottomAxes,'Visible','off')
            case 3
                set(handles.TopAxes,'Visible','off')
                set(handles.BottomAxes,'Visible','on')
        end

        guidata(hFig,handles)
    end
end
```

With the 3 different options:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

And that's it. Good luck!

Comment: thanks I used this and it worked fine . I have another question : can I do the same effect for other buttons ? AKA can I use [visible off ] for more buttons?
edit :I found it it does work for other,thanks mate